# Installing Cappuccino (Objective J)

Tags: installation, cappuccino

I have to confess I am not an expert in Mac OS but I am trying to install Cappuccino.  I ran the script and the following files are now in the "narwhal" subdirectory.  Trouble is, I have no idea what to do next.  There doesn't appear to be an install executable, and no icon has appeared to invoke the development environment.  Any help is appreciated.

These are the downloaded files:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you've downloaded the package on the website, there's a shell script. In the terminal run the bootstrap.sh file:

```
./bootstrap.sh
```

Then, you're set to install Cappuccino. 
Inside the Cappuccino directory type:

```
jake install
```

or sometimes

```
jake sudo-install
```

is required. (it'll complain about permissions if you need to use sudo-install)

That will install Cappuccino itself.

To create a new cappuccino project you'll need to use the "capp" tool

```
capp gen MyNewProjectName
```

or `capp --help`

will tell you how to use some of the more advanced features of the capp tool. 
This will give you a blank project where you can get to work. 
There are other tools you can (and will want to) use when you're ready to deploy, but we can get to those when the time comes.

Additionally, the mailing list is very helpful when it comes to these kinds of questions, and it monitored much more closely than SO. :)

Comment: Thanks Me1000.  As you can see from the directory listing above, I don't have bootstrap or jake.  I tried "capp gen MyNewProjectName" and all I got back was "-bash: capp: command not found"  ??

Comment: The directory above is not what you should have downloaded.

http://cappuccino.org/download/